# TIMESTAMPDIFF in a php foreach-loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating a table in PHP that extracts data from a database, to list movies for a schoolproject. But I also want to list the remaining days until the movies releases.

I have been using the following query in MySQL workbench to calculate days between dates for individual id's. But I don't know how to output that data in my foreach-loop below.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, CURDATE(), 
(SELECT `start` from Movie WHERE id = 1))
```

I'd rather not change the way the table is generated, does someone have a solution? Hopefully my question isnt too vague.

**The variable $res is a two dimensional array for each movie in the database.**

```
public function getTable($res, $hits, $page) {      

    $max = $this->search->GetMaxPages();

    $hitsPerPage = $this->getHitsPerPage(array(2, 5, 10), $hits);
    $navigatePage = $this->getPageNavigation($hits, $page, $max);

    $html = "<div>{$hitsPerPage}</div><table>";
    // The table head
    $html .= "<tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Title " . $this->orderby('title') . "</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Starts " . $this->orderby('start') . "</th>
        <th>Days left</th>
    </tr>";
    // The table rows
    foreach($res AS $key => $val) {
        $html .= "<tr>
            <td class='table-image'><a href='object.php?id={$val->id}'><img src='img.php?src={$val->image}&sharpen&amp;width=120&amp;' alt='{$val->title}' /></a></td>
            <td><a href='object.php?id={$val->id}' class='table-title'>{$val->title}</a></td>
            <td>{$val->genre}</td>
            <td>{$val->start}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>";
    }

    $html .= "</table><div class='pagenav'>" . $navigatePage . "</div>";
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You had better give us a clue what `$res` contains and looks like

Comment: to display data, just use `echo`

Comment: @MubinKhalid _And to become a millionaire just buy a lottery ticket_

Comment: lol, n to go to moon, contact NASA !

Comment: A `print_r($res)` would be more useful, or at least a subset of it that demonstrates its content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your *foreach* loop with my one and give it a try.

```
foreach($res AS $key => $val) {
     $daysLeft = floor((strtotime($val->start) - time())/(60*60*24));
     $daysLeft = ($daysLeft > 0) ? $daysLeft : '0';
     $html .= "<tr>
         <td class='table-image'><a href='object.php?id={$val->id}'><img src='img.php?src={$val->image}&sharpen&amp;width=120&amp;' alt='{$val->title}' /></a></td>
         <td><a href='object.php?id={$val->id}' class='table-title'>{$val->title}</a></td>
         <td>{$val->genre}</td>
         <td>{$val->start}</td>
         <td>$daysLeft</td>
     </tr>";
}
```

Comment: That was just what I was looking for, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Just do a little math.

Place this just below the line `foreach($res AS $key => $val) {`

```
$starttime = $val->start; // get our start time
$start = strtotime("$starttime"); // get epoch time of start time

$datenow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); // time now
$date = strtotime("$datenow"); // get epoch time for right now

$timeremaining = $start- $date; // how much time do we have left

$days = $timeremaining / 86400; // number of seconds in a day
```

Now all you have to do is rewrite your html placing `echo number_format($days);` where you want it to display.

Comment: Also worked like a charm, thanks a bunch to you aswell!